# remove a gmail email tag python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, gmail, imaplib

I'm working with the library `imaplib` following this [example](https://gist.github.com/jasonrdsouza/1674794) to retrieve some attached files from my emails. Now once I have processed the files I'm trying to place the email in a new tag `LMS_processed` and I need to remove them from Inbox to avoid process them later on.

My code to move to a new tag and remove the email from inbox looks like:

```
    m.store(emailid,'+X-GM-LABELS',"LMS_completed")
    m.store(emailid, '-X-GM-LABELS', '/INBOX')
```

However, this is working seamlessly to add the tag but not to untag the email:

[image]

If someone has an idea please let me know it

thanks so much.

Comment: Your slash is going the wrong way.  Try '\\Inbox' or r'\Inbox'.